# Should I use a comma or a colon?

Tags: formatting, editing, punctuation, grammar

I am a bit confused as to whether I should use a comma or a colon for the following sentence:

> Art quickly became a world where I could trust my abilities, a world where I can share my emotions and stories.

or

> Art quickly became a world where I could trust my abilities: a world where I can share my emotions and stories.

Which is more correct?

Comment: Use the best of both worlds! Meet the semicolon!!!      ;

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid I'm going to have to vote to close this, as these sorts of "which sentence is correct" questions belong on [English.SE](https://english.stackexchange.com/) instead. I would migrate the question there, but since you're an unregistered user, I don't think there would be any way for you to retain ownership of it if I did that. I'd suggest reposting the question there instead.

Comment: Not off topic as grammar questions fall into valid Writing SE questions.

Comment: @hszmv As per the description for the [tag:grammar] tag: "questions asking to improve or check grammar of a specific piece are off-topic". I believe that this question falls under that, and is better suited to English.SE, but I'm open to discussion on the matter (perhaps on Meta rather than here).

Comment: I am voting to reopen because this as I believe this is a borderline good question for Writing SE.

Comment: @Nai45 @ hszmv Grammar questions are on topic here at Writing.SE only in writing specific contexts. E.g. How the grammatical rules apply to particular writing styles, or how grammatical choices can impact the tone of writing. This question is simply asking for the correct grammar in this specific situation, this is off-topic by the grammar tag guidance as F1Krazy points out.

Comment: @linksassin Got it!